# Cannot compile PHP 7.4.30 on Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: openssl, php-7.4, php-openssl, ubuntu-22.04

I have an issue trying to manually compile PHP 7.4.x on Ubuntu Server 22.04LTS.

There seems to be a compatibility problem between PHP 7.4 and OpenSSL 3.0 as the php compilation fails with various `OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0` errors.

If PHP7.4 has no OpenSSl 3 support is it still possible to compile it manually on 22.04LTS?

It compiles successfully on 18.04LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: <s>you can't!</s> You need to compile OpenSSL 1.1 from source.

If I may suggest an alternative! check out [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags&page=1&name=7.4)

I have being trying to do the same to install PHP 7.4.30; the problem is caused by Ubuntu's 22.04 usage of libssl3, libssl1.1 (the one we need) was present until impish (21.10)

[image: ubuntu package libssl1.1]

In a response at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/905734) its mentioned that:

You can use `--with-openssl` or `--with-openssl-dir` to solve this problem indicating where your custom openssl build is, for example if you downloaded and built it from source in `/opt/openssl` you could add the following to your build options

```
--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl
```

Digging through some old SO answers I found this example:

```bash
phpbrew install 7.1 +default +openssl=shared -- --with-openssl-dir=/openssl/openssl
```

After checking the official phpbrew wiki I found the following steps to compile and install OpenSSL 1.1 from source in Ubuntu 22.04:

```
cd $HOME
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz
tar xzf $HOME/openssl/openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1i
./Configure --prefix=$HOME/openssl-1.1.1i/bin -fPIC -shared linux-x86_64
make -j 8 
make install
```

Is worth to mention that for me:

1. OpenSSL 1.1.1i works for php 7.4.29

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/openssl-1.1.1i/bin/lib/pkgconfig && \
phpbrew install 7.4.29 +default
```

2. OpenSSL 1.1.1p works for php 7.4.30

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/openssl-1.1.1i/bin/lib/pkgconfig && \
phpbrew install 7.4.30 +default
```

Comment: I have compiled latest openssl 1.1.1 and used --with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl. PHP compiles but shows OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl).

Comment: using openssl=shared results in the same compilation errors. It must be possible to compile 7.4 on 22.04. I am using Docker - but want to use an Ubuntu image...

Comment: I just found some instructions in phpbrew's wiki, I have not tried it yet
https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/Troubleshooting#compiling-php74-with-the-openssl-extension-error-in-ubuntu-2204

Comment: this works in the PHP configure --with-openssl PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/$OPENSSL_VERSION/bin/lib/pkgconfig

Comment: I will update my response, I have also tried and I see that OpenSSL 1.1.1i works for 7.4.29 but 1.1.1p is required for 7.4.30

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using an Ubuntu 22.04 Docker image here is the build for OpenSSL 1.1.1p and the php compilation options:

```
ENV OPENSSL_VERSION openssl-1.1.1p
RUN set -xe \
    && curl -fSL "https://www.openssl.org/source/$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz" -o "$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && ls -al \
    && tar xzf $OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && cd $OPENSSL_VERSION \
    && ./Configure --prefix=/opt/$OPENSSL_VERSION/bin -fPIC -shared linux-x86_64 \
    && make -j 8  \
    && make install \
    && export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/$OPENSSL_VERSION/bin/lib/pkgconfig
```

Add the following to the php compilation configure options

```
--with-openssl \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/$OPENSSL_VERSION/bin/lib/pkgconfig \
```

> PHP 7.4.30 (cli) (built: Jun 28 2022 15:51:41) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
> The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.4.30, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

```
 openssl
 
 OpenSSL support => enabled OpenSSL
 Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1p 21 Jun 2022
 OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1p  21 Jun 2022
 Openssl default config => /opt/openssl-1.1.1p/bin/ssl/openssl.cnf
```